# node.js + express Framework

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express framework in node.js. In that i have some clarifications in my route.js file.

Route.js:

```
app.get('/aaaa/bbbb/:cccc',function(req, res) {  ------------>first      
    var level1 = req.params.cccc;
    return service.getfilterdata( level1req, res);
});   

app.get('/aaaa/bbbb/dddd',function(req, res) { ------------- >second
    var level0 = req.query.level0;   
    return service.getkeydetails(level0, req, res);    
});
```

When i type the url for 2nd app.get , my first app.get is called. Whether express will look for only how many slash("/") in the route.. How can i solve this problem.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

It's normal, in your first root, you have `/aaaa/bbbb/:cccc`, the `:ccccc` used to pass anything.
In your case, if you request `/aaaa/bbbb/dddd`, express check all roots in order. And the first checked is `/aaaa/bbbb/:cccc`.

To fix that, you have just to invert this two functions :

```
app.get('/aaaa/bbbb/dddd',function(req, res) { ------------- >first
    var level0 = req.query.level0;   
    return service.getkeydetails(level0, req, res);    
});
app.get('/aaaa/bbbb/:cccc',function(req, res) {  ------------>second      
    var level1 = req.params.cccc;
    return service.getfilterdata( level1req, res);
});
```

Comment: express will test routes one after the other until it find one that matches. In your case if you pass `/aaaa/bbbb/eeee`, the first url check false, the second check true, express stop test on the second. If you pass `/aaaa/bbbb/dddd` first check true, express stop here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your specifics routes above your binded routes: invert the place of your app.get functions.